# NHibernate query cache makes one request per row to fetch entities

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, second-level-cache

I'm trying out the second level cache in NHibernate. With this code:

```
return session.Query<Payment>()
    .Cacheable()
    .OrderByDescending(payment => payment.Created)
    .Skip((page - 1)*pageSize)
    .Take(pageSize).ToArray();
```

If the entities are not in the cache, it will lead to queries like these being executed:

```
select ... from Payment where Id = 1
select ... from Payment where Id = 2
select ... from Payment where Id = 3
```

If 100 rows are returned, 100 of these would be executed. I.e. a big performance issue. It would be better if just this query was executed:

```
select ... from Payment where Id in (1,2,3)
```

That the entities doesn't exist in the cache can be because of no entity cache configured, limited size of the caches or that the entities in the cache has been expired or removed from the cache.

To not be forced to rely 100% on the entity-cache, is it possible to change the way NHibernate queries for that "missing" entity data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)Is it possible to configure NHibernate (I use FluentNHibernate with automapping) to also cache the entities?

Yes it is possible to configure Nhibernate second level cache to cache entities.
Refer [Here](http://www.klopfenstein.net/lorenz.aspx/using-syscache-as-secondary-cache-in-nhibernate)

2)And to not be forced to rely 100% on the cache, is it possible to change the way NHibernate queries for that "missing" entity data?

[Did you enable "cache.use_query_cache" property in the config file?](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/02/09/quickly-setting-up-and-using-nhibernate-s-second-level-cache.aspx)

Comment: 1. I managed to get the entity cache working with FNH conventions. But it doesn't cache the entire entity, data from related tables isn't joined even though I use eager loading.

Comment: 2. Yes query cache is enabled. And the queries are cached. But the query cache only contains ids. To get the data they will access either the entity cache or do one query per row to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the same cache region in order to "activate" the same caching rules for collections as the main entity. Otherwise it will only cache the main entity, and fetch the collection again if the main entity was loaded from 2nd level cache.

I don't know if this is supported with FluentNhibernate though, you will need to check the docs.

It looks like Collections (Bag) has support for .Cache(CacheMapping mapping)

http://fluentnhibernate.org/api/FluentNHibernate.MappingModel/CacheMapping.htm

Comment: I found instance.Cache.IncludeAll() ( http://fluentnhibernate.org/api/FluentNHibernate.Conventions.Instances/ICacheInstance.htm ) but it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: You should be adding Cache at your collection declaration. Post your mapping.

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't see that it wasn't a collection you were working with. Then you should declare CacheRegion on your entitymapping for Payment